# How to use the same libraries in all the classes inside a namespace

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, using

I'm implementing various classes in a common folder and namespace all of which need to be able to deserialize JSON, so all the classes need the

```
using using System.Globalization; 
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

directives. I was wondering if there is a way to make them all use said libraries rather than pasting it into every new class .cs file or writing all the classes in the same .cs file. I've tried putting the using directives inside the namespace but it doesn't carry over to the other .cs files. It might be worth mentioning I'm working on a wpf C# .net framework desktop application.

Sample class without the using directives

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MLaRealERP.Models
{
    internal class ClienteP
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("dni")]
        public string DNI { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("ruc")]
        public string RUC { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("nombres")]
        public string Nombres { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("apellidos")]
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("celular")]
        public string Celular { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: And what problem are you trying to solve with this "feature"? Is so much a problem to press CTRL+. and add the proposed using if it is missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 10 you can use the `global` modifier on the `using` directive but this is equivalent to adding it to every file in the project. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

If you're on an earlier version, short answer is no.